# Ode with Piecewise function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, periodic-functions

[image]

We can write this $$12x"+36x'+48x=f(t)$$  my main problem is how to solve this non-homogeneous ODE

I know how to do this as 2 different ode

unfortunately its not in a syllabus which doesn't use laplace transform

but is there a better way to do all at once considering its periodic